# Left-to-Right vs Encoder-decoder Models

Tags: natural-language-processing, objective-functions, bert, gpt, encoder-decoder

[Xu et al. (2022)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2202.13169.pdf) distinguishes between popular pre-training methods for language modeling: (see Section 2.1 PRETRAINING METHODS)

- Left-to-Right:

> Auto-regressive, Left-to-right models, predict the probability of a
> token given the previous tokens.

- Encoder-Decoder:

> An encoder-decoder model first uses an encoder to encode an input
> sequence, and then uses a left-to-right LM to decode an output
> sequence conditioned on the input sequence.

My question is, what are the differences between those two methods?
Do they suggest that the first method is a decoder-only? If so, what is the input to this decoder?

Based on what I know about auto-regressive models and the above definition, I understand that in Left-to-Right, we predict the $i$-th token given the $1,...,i-1$ tokens (which could be our past predictions).